# Create a custom UIKeyboard In-App

Tags: swift, ios8, uikeyboard, ios-app-extension

I have a UITextField that only requires specific character input, and I was wondering if it was possible to create a custom keyboard inside an iOS 8 app. Specifically the characters i want are a collection of logical symbols (which have unicode values) and some standard characters like parenthesis etc.

I would ideally like to override/overlay the current buttons on a UIKeyboard but still have the same kind of functionality such as being able to input characters where the cursor position is currently in the text field.

I know that you can create custom keyboards through an app extension but this is not what i want, i just want a keyboard to be used inside the app and no where else. If i am wrong, can i create an app extension keyboard to only be used within the app? that doesn't have to installed via Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the inputView property on your UITextField and return a view containing the keyboard. You must implement the keyboard functionality yourself, there is no way to access anything on the built in keyboard.

Comment: You can provide a custom keyboard by setting the inputView of a UITextField at runtime, no need to override it.